# CSS displaying correctly in localhost site, but not on actual website

Tags: css

Firstly, I am still learning and fairly new to this profession so feel free to correct the code I have that is wrong.

The issue I have is that on my localhost solution, my css grid code is working the way I want it to (see 1st pic below). When it's uploaded, it is not (see 2nd pic below). I have used a method found on another website (https://css-tricks.com/new-year-new-job-lets-make-a-grid-powered-resume/) and it works on my CV, but it's not working on my portfolio post.

Should look like this!
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0bin.png)

But looks like this...
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef2gk.png)

In specifics, the css file (index.css) is getting called for an id on the parent div that contains all the sections of a grid, but the index.css is not getting called for the class in the parent div, nor is index.css being applied to any of the classes on the sections of the grid. In the localhost, index.css is working correctly across these sections. **When I check index.css on the server side, it is up to date and has all the classes that I need** which is what is making me scratch my head so much...

What I have tried is a 'hard refresh' (ctrl+f5, shift+f5, etc.), turned my Cloudflare into developer mode, and I have also allowed some time to see if it was just a slow upload on the server side.

HTML code;

```
<div id="banner">
    <!--Title-->
    <div class="container py-2">
        <div class="col-12 py-0 px-2">
            <h3><u>KPI Management Dashboard</u></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-sections" id="content">

    <section class="grid-area-portfolio portfolio-overview" style="margin-left: 15px;">
        <div class="p-3">
            <p style="color: #545454;"><b>OVERVIEW</b></p>
            <p>
                text here
            </p>
            <p>
                text here
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="grid-area-portfolio portfolio-role" style="margin-left: 15px;">
        <div class="p-3">
            <p style="color: #545454;"><b>MY ROLE</b></p>
            <p>
                <b>Graduate Software Developer</b> for&nbsp;<a href="https://nantltd.co.uk/">Nant Ltd</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                UI Design, Prototyping, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, MySQL
            </p>
            <p>May 2020 - July 2020</p>
            Go to the&nbsp;<a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard Page</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS code (index.css);

```
#banner {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /*color: #545454;*/
    /*border-top: 2px solid rgba(82,82,82,0.4);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(82,82,82,0.4);*/
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 5px 10px 0;
}

#banner h3 {
    color: #545454;
    border-top: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255, .95);
    transition: border-top ease-in-out 0.25s;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#banner h3:hover {
    border-top: 4px solid #AFFC41;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 75%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 5px 10px 0;
    display: grid;
}

.portfolio-sections {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "portfolio-overview portfolio-overview portfolio-role" 
        "portfolio-background portfolio-background portfolio-background" 
        "portfolio-problem portfolio-problem portfolio-problem" 
        "portfolio-users portfolio-users portfolio-users" 
        "portfolio-solution portfolio-solution portfolio-solution" 
        "portfolio-results portfolio-results portfolio-results";
}

.grid-area-portfolio {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.portfolio-overview {
    grid-area: portfolio-overview;
}

.portfolio-role {
    grid-area: portfolio-role;
}
```

A link to this codepen shows it works there - https://codepen.io/gileswking/pen/abdgOVo

But a link to my actual site shows it doesn't work there - https://www.code-grey.co.uk/portfolio/dashboard_case_study.php

I would appreciate any help, and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your actual site looks fine to me in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: It looks fine to me 2.

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: Do you know... This is making think I'm going crazy. It hasn't worked for damn near two days and I have just refreshed and it's working fine... huh... Thanks...

Comment: When you push to your server sometimes its best to clear cache and refresh to ensure your changes are picked up

Comment: Hamid - I am on Google Chrome and it is up to date.
Lowkase - Do I have to clear the server cache (if this is a thing???), or do you mean my browser cache? I did clear the browser cache yesterday afternoon around this time and I built the page on Sunday evening, and haven't cleared my cache since.

Comment: @GilesKing Always open in incognito mode in chrome after a fresh deployment to see latest changes.

Comment: If you check the site now, it is no longer working. I haven't made any changes to the site since uploading this question. I have no way to answer this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out if I click *Development Mode* on my Cloudflare CDN, it works for 24 hours, then disables itself which implies it's an improper setup on Cloudflare. After going through the setup with a friend, it is now working.